# JqueryUi autocomplete combobox button

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am using a jQuery UI auto-complete combobox in my project, and modified the CSS as so:

```
.custom-combobox {
    border: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    width:76%;
    height:18px;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
 top:-3px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    border: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    width:76%;
    height:18px;
```

}

But I can't get the positioning of the button right - it is either a little up or below the field instead of inline, and because of the percentage width it sometimes goes on to the next line.

How can I get the button fixed next to the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is wrap the field and button into a div, and that helps me to move them around together. For example:

```
<form id="nameForm" action="/submit" method="post">
<div>
    <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</div>
</form>
```

That way I can force the wrapper to be big enough for both inputs, and if they cannot fit together they would move together onto the next line.

```
<style type="text/css">
#nameForm {
  width: 500px;
}
#nameForm div > input {
  width: 350px;
}
#nameForm div > input + input[type=submit] {
  width: 100px;
}
</style>
```